# How to destroy all threads on KeyboardInterrupt (Destroying Main App)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, class, thread-safety

I have Main app there i can open thread with chatbot.

```
def run_bot(self):
    bot = TelegramBot(self.engine.CurrentBot)
    bot.start()
```

Then i am closing my app, i need to destroy all my treads. I am using Stop button in PyCharm. It returns `KeyboardInterrupt` but bots aren't killed. They are continue working with app.

`Telegram bot` is a child class of `Thread`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you stop the main process, all child threads are killed automatically. You might have to press the stop button twice in PyCharm, first to kill the main thread, then once it shows the skull sign, press that skull to kill the whole process (and all child threads).